# How to check for an object property?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
if(window.NS1.foob)
```

I want to check and see if foob exists.

However, I'm getting this error

```
NS1 id undefined.
```

The problem is I need to test for the existence of foob, not NS1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to check for NS1 first.  Window is the global object, and you don't need to specify it, as it is implicit.

```
if (window.NS1 && window.NS1.foob)
```

before checking for foob.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: actually, you should use if (window.NS1 && NS1.foob) in case NS1  is not defined also...

Answer (score 8):

One way is:

```
if(window.NS1 && window.NS1.foob)
```

Answer (score 3):

There can be many ways, following are two:

```
if(window.NS1 && window.NS1.foob){
    //your code
}
```

.

```
try{
    if(window.NS1.foob) {
        //your code
    }
} catch (err) {
    if(err instanceof TypeError) {
        //your code
    } else {
       throw err;
    }
}
```

Second one should be preferred, if NS1 not being present is an exceptional condition (i.e., won't occur frequently) and also if you want to handle it in a different way (compared to when foob is not present).

Answer (score -1):

This works for me.

```
var NS1 = window.NS1 = function(){};
NS1.foob = "bar";
NS1.hasOwnProperty('foob') ? alert('Yep') : alert('Nope');
```

Edit: Not sure why I got downvoted, but maybe I misinterpreted the question. (Although I clearly overcomplicated it  bit)

Comment: the reason you got down voted is maybe coz you are not performing a check on NS1 (which is the actual question) u are basically overwriting it. It may happen, that NS1 may sometimes have value assigned to it. Hope I'm making sense here.